# How javascript operator is working in following conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I've two conditions as below where both are true. 
What is difference between i==5 and 5==i ?

```
var i=5; 
if(i==5){
  console.log("hello");
}
if(5==i){
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: Duplicated because of "Type coercion"?  The OP is asking about operand position.

Comment: I think both are different. I'm not asking about == and ====

Comment: There is no difference in your conditional. Both evaluate to 5 = 5 which evaluates to true.

Comment: @mplungjan  mark it not duplicate if not related to Type coercion

Comment: Right now there is no difference assuming i indeed is the integer 5 and it is in your example. So there is no question here.